# Как давно делаешь что-то?

Tags: общие-вопросы, смысл

Правильно ли будет сказать "**Как давно** / **Давно** учишь английский язык?"
Или же правильно будет "**Как долго** учишь английский язык?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь правильнее - **долго**.
***"Как долго ты учишь язык?"***
**Долго** - это про промежуток времени.

**Давно** - это о событии, точке во времени.
Можно сказать **"Как давно ты начал учить язык?"**.

Да, иногда в разговорной речи "давно" подменяет собой "долго", но это если не ошибка, то стилистическая небрежность.

Answer (score 0):

Мне всё-таки кажется, что учить можно кого-то, а язык  ИЗУЧАЮТ, а не учат. Поэтому, Молодой Человек, правильно будет спросить: "Как долго ИЗУЧАЕШЬ английский язык?" Слово "учить" имеет какой-то просторечный оттенок.

Comment: Просторечный? Не уверен. Большой толковый словарь: учить **8**. (св. выучить). что. Повторяя, запоминать, усваивать. У. урок. У. роль. У. басню наизусть. У. таблицу умножения. У. ботанику, историю.

Comment: Артём, я имела в виду не вообще значение слова "учить", а сочетание слов "учить язык". Мне кажется, здесь возможен речевой недочёт в нарушении лексической сочетаемости данных слов. А к отдельно взятому слову у меня никаких претензий. Замечательное слово!

Comment: В примерах есть "У. ботанику, историю". По-вашему "учить язык" звучит хуже , чем "учить ботанику"?

Comment: Да в общем-то неплохо. У меня несколько отрицательное лексическое наполнение данного слова. (Из личного опыта: для меня "учить " сочетается только со словом "правило"  и синонимично слову "зубрить").

Comment: Согласен, нос лишь отчасти. В моем восприятии "учить" тоже напоминает о школе, но шире, чем "зубрить".  "Изучать" - более высокий стиль, глубокое проникновение в материал.